# How to run part of a click function only once

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Every time I click the button, it slide down and run the code. It is good. But if I slide it up and down again, it run the code again. So first time, I have 1,4,5. I click the button again, it slide up, click it again, if I keep clicking button, It will become 1,4,5,1,4,5,1,4,5,1,4,5. I only want to run it once, how can I achieve that?

```
    $('#tag_toggle').on('click',function(){
        $('.taxonomies').slideToggle();

        var user_load=$('#find_members_t').val();
        var myArray=user_load.split(',');

        // length-1 remove the last commas
        for (var i=0; i<myArray.length-1; i++){
             $('#find_members').append(
                 "<div class='display_box' id='display_box'>"+myArray[i]+"</div>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about you set a variable like `alreadyLoaded` and if `alreadyLoaded==true` you don't run the code again.

Comment: or perhaps before you load the new data you check to see if the elements already exist like `if($('#find_members').find('div.display_box').length == 0){ ...run code... }`

Comment: note that you can't repeat ID's on page , they are unique by defintiion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#tag_toggle').one('click',function(){ // <-----------'one', not 'on'!
    var user_load=$('#find_members_t').val();
    var myArray=user_load.split(',');

    // length-1 remove the last commas
    for (var i=0; i<myArray.length-1; i++){
         $('#find_members').append(
             "<div class='display_box' id='display_box'>"+myArray[i]+"</div>");
    }
})
.on('click',function(){
    $('.taxonomies').slideToggle();
});
```